# how do you hide an image in Tumblr's permalink page?

Tags: css, tumblr, permalinks

I want to have my own thumbnails for video posts on my main tumblr page....and show the video only in the permalink page with out the thumbnail.

here's an example site of what I'm trying to do: 
http://devour.com/  (not tumblr but same idea)

I figured the best method is to post the thumbnail as a photo post, with the video embedded. Then hide the image in the permalink page.

so my question is...how do I hide the image in the permalink page?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding the image on the permalink page, use the theme operators `{block:IndexPage}` and `{block:PermalinkPage}` to only include the content that you need.

```
{block:Posts}
  {block:Photo}

  <!-- On the Index, show only the Image / Cover -->
  {block:IndexPage}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}">
  {/block:IndexPage}
  <!-- On the Permalink, show only the Caption, which contains the video -->
  {block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:Caption}
    {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
  {/block:PermalinkPage}

  {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
```

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables